# Getting user input and load it on FPU stack - what I am doing wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf

I want to write the program which takes user inputs and perform some calculations on these numbers using fpu. I am using C function `scanf`. For my calculations I will also need the number -4, so I also declared it in the code. For now, I'm just trying to display the value taken from the user to make sure that they load well, and only later I will go to the calculations.

I take the numbers from the user and load the fpu stack as shown below. Basically everything is fine, but the number at [esp + 8] is always displayed with an additional fractional part, e.g. if I enter 2 - it displays 2.000001, if 3 it displays 3.000001 and each number analogously. 
I think it's a small mistake but I can't find it

```
        [bits 32]

        call print1
       formatA: db "a = ", 0
print1: 
       call[ebx+3*4];
       sub esp, 8
       push esp
       call scan_a
formatA2: db "%lf", 0
scan_a:
       call [ebx+4*4]
       add esp, 2*4

       call print2
formatB: db "b = ", 0
print2:
       call[ebx+3*4];
       sub esp, 8
       push esp
      call scan_b
formatB2: db "%lf", 0
scan_b:
       call [ebx+4*4]
       add esp, 2*4

       call getaddr

format db "x1 = %lf", 0xA,
       db "x2 = %lf", 0xA, 0

offset equ $ - format
minusfour  dq -4.0

getaddr:

        finit

        ;mov esi, [esp]
        ;lea esi, [esi+offset] ; esi = -4

        fld qword[esp]
        fld qword[esp+8]

        fstp qword[esp+4]
        fstp qword[esp+12]

        call[ebx+3*4] ;print function
        add esp, 3*4

        push 0
        call[ebx+0*4]
```

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: It looks like you left out a `call` to `print1`.  Without that your code makes no sense; execution would go through the data instead of over, and nothing would push a format string for `printf`, and your final `pop` would be unbalanced.

Comment: `%lf` reads a double but you only pop the low 32 bits of it (into an integer register!).  That loads part of the value, not the address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, of course I have ```call``` to ```print1```  in my code, here is my miestake and I pasted it incorrectly in the question. 
Regarding the second remark, I understand why this will not work, but I still have no idea how to solve my problem. I will be grateful for any additional tips.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  From just the fragments you posted, the problem cannot be diagnosed.

Comment: @fuz I have edited my main post and added what I was able to "find out" so far, tried to describe my problem as accurately as possible and inserted all the code.

Comment: @nath425 Your code is still just a fragment.  I cannot assemble and test it on my own system because it's missing all sorts of pieces.  Please post a [mcve].  This must be a complete program.  Also, you seem to have omitted `ret` instructions all over the place.  Are they missing just in the code you pasted or are they missing in your actual code as well?

Comment: @fuz I expect this program is not exemplary, and it can be hard to help, but unfortunately this is my study project and we are taught in such a strange way and it really is all the code. (even when I'm looking for some sample programs on the internet I can't find anything like that). So there is no ```ret``` instruction in it. But I will really be grateful for anything that will work, e.g. a good example of how it should look like loading onto the fpu stack

Comment: @nath425 But without a `ret` instruction... how do your functions return?  The thing is, before I can even start to debug problems with the FPU stack, I must exclude all other error sources.  And your functions not returning is the most glaring one.

Comment: @fuz As I mentioned, I write all programs in the same way as we do in class. We didn't use the ret statement in any of the programs (which may be incorrect, but I'm just taught, so it's hard for me to refer to it at all). At the same time, I know that it can be difficult for others to understand, but maybe someone has encountered such practices

Comment: @nath425 Then I can't help you, sorry.  The way you are taught is extremely weird and I don't think I can help you with anything because I don't understand what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @fuz I understand, after all, thank you for your interest and willingness to help

Comment: The way I see it, the value is already at `esp+4` so you don't have to do anything. Setting `esi` is pointless too. So you can just delete the 4 instructions after `finit` and it should work.

Comment: @Jester thank you, indeed it was very oversized and basically works, but e.g. if I enter the number 2, it displays 2.000001, if I enter 3 it is 3.000001. It seems to me that this is a small mistake but I can not determine where. Can you taka a look again?

Comment: Edit your question to show the current code. The issue sounds like you corrupt part of the number by accident.

Comment: @Jester I edited my question, added all the code. I show how to try to get two numbers because I need 2 of them eventually.

Comment: It doesn't work because you never allocate space for the numbers. With one it accidentally worked because you just overwrote random stuff on the stack. Before the `push esp` do `sub esp, 8` to allocate space each time. Also a `qword` is 8 bytes so `+4` and `+8` can't work.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, but I have one more question. I did as you wrote (I also pasted the current code). It seemed to me that now these values ​​are in [esp] and [esp + 8], but apparently I am wrong. Can you tell me how to get to these values ​​now? I know I'm probably asking about the basics, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @Jester Once again, thanks a lot! Now I have finally managed to get to these values.